# Data frame column manipulation based on %in% vector R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have 2 atomic vectors:

```
mcc <- as.character(c(1:10))
ctyc <- as.character(c(2:11))
```

And i have a data frame:

```
xmcc <- as.character(c(8:12))
xctyc <- as.character(c(1:4,12))
df <- data.frame(xmcc, xctyc)
colnames(df) <- c("mcc", "ctyc")

  mcc ctyc
1   8    1
2   9    2
3  10    3
4  11    4
5  12   12
```

My desired output is :
logic is that if mcc in the dataframe do exist in the vector- mcc, it will return the mcc, 9999 otherwise. Same logic for column ctyc

```
  mcc ctyc mccNew ctycNew
1   8    1     8      999
2   9    2     9        2
3  10    3    10        3
4  11    4  9999        4
5  12   12  9999      999
```

My attempt:

```
df$mccNew <- ifelse(df$mcc %in% mcc, df$mcc, "9999")
df$ctycNew <- ifelse(df$ctyc %in% ctyc, df$ctyc, "999")
```

While it can't shown to desired output.

Comment: If you set `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` for the `data.frame`, it will work.

Comment: Then shouldn't it be: `df$mccNew <- ifelse(df$mcc %in% mcc, mcc, "9999")`?

Comment: @P.Routh No - `mcc` is a vector, you just need the single `df$mcc` in a cell

Comment: Thanks all! It works for @Val solution. Do you mind explain why it works?

Comment: @useR This comes from the way R uses factor variables ... it can make indexing difficult and produce results you don't want. So if you don't need factors, it's better to not use them. So `data.frame` converts strings to factors on a default basis. If you set then `stringsAsFactors` to `FALSE`, there are just plain strings which can be easily used for standard indexing.

Answer (score 0):

We can use **match** to accomplish this:

- `A match B`: produce an index vector where index[i] represent the location in B matched with A[i], `NA` if not.

So:

```
> matchedIndex.mcc <- match(df$mcc, mcc)
> matchedIndex.ctyc <- match(df$ctyc, ctyc)
> df$mccNew <- ifelse(!is.na(matchedIndex.mcc), mcc[matchedIndex.mcc], 9999)
> df$ctycNew <- ifelse(!is.na(matchedIndex.ctyc), ctyc[matchedIndex.ctyc], 9999)
> df
  mcc ctyc mccNew ctycNew
1   8    1      8    9999
2   9    2      9       2
3  10    3     10       3
4  11    4   9999       4
5  12   12   9999    9999
```

Comment: it gives 1,2,3 instead of 8,9,10 if i use your solution.

Comment: @useR I misunderstood the function **match**, which gives a matched index vector. Check my updates.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Map` to add both variables in a single line like this

```
df[c("mccNew", "ctycNew")] <- Map(function(x, y) ifelse(x %in% y, x, "9999"),
                                  df, list(mcc, ctyc))
```

Here, the left hand side provides slots with variable names to add to the data.frame. The right hand side runs in parallel between elements of two lists, a list of the data.frame variables and a list of the vectors that you use for checking. `Map` outputs a list with of length equal to the two list arguments, each list element containing a vector the length of the rows of df. Note that if your data.frame has more variables, you will want to subset to the variables of interest in the second argument to `Map`.

This returns

```
df
  mcc ctyc mccNew ctycNew
1   8    1      4    9999
2   9    2      5       3
3  10    3      1       4
4  11    4   9999       5
5  12   12   9999    9999
```